# MySQL: How do I remove/skip the first row (before the headers) from my stored procedure result?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I am calling a stored procedure which results in the following output

```
CALL `resale`.`reportProfitAndLossSummary`(3,' ',599025,TRUE);
```

OUTPUT:

```
"CONCAT('"',
                   CONCAT_WS('","',
                           "Promoter",
                           "Event",
                           "Event Description",
                           "Zone",
                           "Tickets Unsold",
        "
""Promoter","Event","Event Description","Zone","Tickets Unsold","Avg. Unsold Price","Tickets Sold","Avg. Sold Price","Avg. Cost","Profit","Revenue""
""Qcue","10/2/2022 1:15 PM Pirates @ Cardinals","Pirates @ Cardinals","1/3B Field Box",0,,16,149.761250,42.000000,1724.18,2396.18"
```

I exported the result to .csv and discovered that a new code chunk is created above the header which distorts the structure of the file. Is there a way to skip this code chunk. I tried "-N" "-ss" since the code chunk appears as the header and none of those worked in MySQLWorkbench. Turning the header option to "FALSE" in the stored procedure call removes the actual headers and not the undesired code.

The stored procedure was developed by someone else so I am not sure where to begin fixing this. The goal is remove the undesired code from the query result itself not the .csv export.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @KenWhite I have updated the question with code snippets instead.

Comment: You would have to start to fix it by locating the source for the stored procedure. Without that, we can't help.

Comment: @KenWhite I see. Is there no way to skip the first line of the query result? I don't have the permission to alter the stored procedure so locating the source will not help, unfortunately.

Comment: You can't affect the output without altering what produces it, and that would be the stored procedure code. Your only option is to process the output in an external app or script to remove the extra header row.